# Не настраивается контент записи у Facebook bulatkamalov2008

Tags: php, facebook-api, share, ya-share2, facebooksdk

Использую апи яндекса. С Вк все отлично работает, а вот с ФБ нет. Вот код

```html
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook"
    data-url="http://smartwalk.dev1.msoft.su/frontend/web/index.php"
    data-title="блабла"
    data-size="m"
    data-description="вавыаываываыва"
    data-image="http://vk.com/images/vk32.png"
    data-counter>
</div>
```

Я пробовал задавать значения для facebook отдельно, но всё равно не работает.

Подскажите как настроить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же просто пробовал юзать апи самого ФБ, но настроить текст картинку и прочее у записи не получилось. Помогите плз)

Answer (score 2):

В общем разобрался, надо в фейсбуке зарегать своё приложение, потом загуглить что такое Open Graph, вставить в нужную страницу метатеги

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" name="app_id" content="app_id" />
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://site.loc" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="http://vk.com/images/vk32.png" />
```

Потом пойти [сюда](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) и [сюда](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/). Ну и там высветится, что не так, а что так.

Comment: А что если текст надо формировать динамически, без использования мета тегов, нигде не могу найти решение